# How to create local effect in ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

How can I do something like that in ngrx/effects:

```
// I want to handle a sign up effect
return this.actions$.ofType(user.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS)
   .map((action: user.SignUpSuccessAction) => action.payload)
   .mergeMap(() => {
      // then I have to call two other async actions to add new records
      return [
         new userOptions.Add(new UserOptionsModel());
         new userInfo.Add(new UserInfoModel());
      ];
   })
```

How can I handle success actions for both userOptions and userInfo actions and then redirect to a Dashboard page? I don't want to redirect to the Dashboard page if I dispatch userOptions.Add and userInfo.Add actions outside user.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS sequence, from other pages for example.

**ANSWER**

Victor Savkin. State Management Patterns and Best Practices with NgRx
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vX2vG0o-rpM

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@ngrx/router-store](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store):

```
return this.actions$.ofType(user.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS)
   .mergeMap(() => {
      // then I have to call two other async actions to add new records
      return [
         new userOptions.Add(new UserOptionsModel()),
         new userInfo.Add(new UserInfoModel()),
         go(['/path', { routeParam: 1 }], { query: 'string' });
      ];
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

first:

```
return this.actions$.ofType(user.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS)
   .mergeMap(() => {
      // then I have to call two other async actions to add new records
      return [
         new userOptions.Add(new UserOptionsModel());
         new userInfo.Add(new UserInfoModel());
      ];
   })
   .map((action) => {
      if(action instanceof UserInfoModel){
        /// latest
      }
   })
```

second:

you can use `map` twice instead of `mergeMap`.

```
return this.actions$.ofType(user.SIGN_UP_SUCCESS)
       .map(toPayload)
       .map(() => {
          return new userOptions.Add(new UserOptionsModel());                 
       })
       .map(() => {
             return new userInfo.Add(new UserInfoModel());
       })
       .map(() => {
             //the end
       })
```

**** `map(toPayload)` do this: `map((action: user.SignUpSuccessAction) => action.payload)`

`import { toPayload } from '@ngrx/effects'`

have a nice day :-)

Comment: You can do this:
`
map(({payload}: user.SignUpSuccessAction) => 
  
    //Use payload
 
)
`
instead of `map(toPayload)`